# Linking to jQuery Mobile page generated with Knockout foreach doesn't work

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I created a main page with jQuery Mobile in which there is a list generated with a Knockout `foreach` template, based on a model created with the mapping plugin. From each item in the template there is a button that should link to a page generated with another knockout `foreach` template.

The `href` of the button is populated with a custom model entry that has the '#' prefix and the page id.

Yet, non of the buttons actually open any of the pages.

See detailed example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/VSVA7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page should be child of <body/>. but, your page template code is wrapped with another <div> element.

if you want to use template without parent DOMElement, use KO virtual element like below

```
<!-- ko binding: binding_context -->
    TEMPLATE
<!-- /ko -->
```

In this case,

```
<!-- ko foreach: Questions -->
<div data-role="page" data-bind="attr: { id: Id }" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="content" data-bind="html: Id">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwdoh/VSVA7/2/) and paste its Full HTML code.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"  style="width:100%;">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="foreach: Questions">
            <li class="listItem">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: IdUrl }, text: Subject" ></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- ko foreach: Questions -->
<div data-role="page" data-bind="attr: { id: Id }" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1 data-bind="text: Subject"></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-bind="html: Id">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```